# Zurb Foundation Accordion & Slick Slider not working together

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, slick.js

I'm having problems getting Foundation's Accordion to work with Slick Slider. I'm using Foundation 5.5.

If I remove the Slick jquery scripts, Accordion works. As soon as I apply Slick, Accordion stops working.

Could you geniuses have a look please? http://jpawebsites.com/test/

Comment: Might be worth creating another test page with the slider code present (thus demonstrating the broken accordion) to see if it's possible to spot any differences, and locate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I have just enter `$('.banner-slider').slick();` into the chrome console.

Slider and accordion seems to work.

I use this combination on serveral sites